# ASP.Net VB DropDownList first value is always selected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms

I am making a website in ASP.NET using VB.NET. I have a `DropDownList` and when I try to pass its value to the next page but it always sends the first item in the `DropDownList` rather than the selected one.

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
              ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
              Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim id As String
    id = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Accounting/Ledger.aspx?id=" + id)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure if you bind **DropDownList1** inside **Page Load** event, it is inside **Not IsPostBack**.

Otherwise, DropDownList will always return first item.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) ...
   If Not IsPostBack Then
      DropDownList1.DataSource = DATASOURCE
      DropDownList1.DataBind()
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do I put for datasource if my drop down list gets its items from a .txt file

Comment: @user3151557 There are multiple way of getting items from a .txt file depending on the format. Please post your code.